# Execute script from Python code

Tags: python, bash, shell

I generated a dot file using Python.

Each time the file is generated, I need to run a script in the Terminal to convert it to a pdf file or an image.

This is the script:

```
dot -Tpdf somefile.dot -o somefile.pdf
```

I was wondering if it is possible to execute this script in the current folder, from within my Python code.

Comment: The first point in [the guideline on how to ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says that you should search, and research.  What have you tried searching/researching so far, before you asked this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os` module allows you to execute custom scripts like this

```
import os

os.system("dot -Tpdf somefile.dot -o somefile.pdf")
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

Answer (score 0):

better to use `subprocess.Popen` will have track of error and output:

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(["dot -Tpdf somefile.dot -o somefile.pdf"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output,err = child.communicate()
```